# Static method to create an object instead of constructor

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, smart-pointers

I'm creating a GUI in my C++ application and I have a class called `GUIObject` which is base class for all other components, like for example `Button`, `CheckBox`, `Window` etc.

I also have a class `GUIObjectsStorage`, which consists of all `GUIObject`s that are created. So far I've been working with raw pointers, so I just had this constructor for `GUIObject` class:

```
GUIObject::GUIObject() :
{
    GUIObjectsStorage::Instance().addObject(this);
}
```

And it was ok for my needs, because whenever I wanted to access specific object, I just took it from `GUIObjectsStorage`. But now I'm trying to move into use of smart pointers, so that `GUIObjectsStorage` now stores array of `std::shared_ptr<GUIObject>` instead of raw pointers and I can't use my constructor as I used it before:

```
GUIObject::GUIObject() :
{
    GUIObjectsStorage::Instance().addObject(std::shared_ptr<GUIObject>(this));
}
```

because for example:

```
// Somewhere in code
std::shared_ptr<Button> bt = std::shared_ptr<Button>(new Button());
```

Basically I'd now have two `shared_ptr`s (one here, second in `GUIObjectsStorage`, because it was added in `Button`'s constructor) which both have reference count = 1, yet both point to the same object in memory. Then if one of them dies, object itself is being destroyed too.

So I came up with an idea to maybe make private constructor for all classes inheriting from `GUIObject` and create a static method which would create and return `std::shared_ptr` and it's copy add to `GUIObjectsStorage`. This way I could have `shared_ptr`s with reference count = 2 which is correct:

```
class Button : public GUIObject 
{
private:
    // ...
    Button();
public:
    // ...
    static std::shared_ptr<Button>  create(); 
}

std::shared_ptr<Button> Button::create()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Button> bt = std::shared_ptr<Button>(new Button());
    GUIObjectsStorage::Instance().addObject(bt);

    return bt;
}
```

By hiding constructor I could be sure that nobody will create an object in different way than by using `create()` method.

But is this good way of designing this? If not, what could be a better solution for this problem?

Comment: Looks good to me. Also, I thought the entire point of shared_ptr was to avoid this sort of issue?

Comment: @Polar Actually I think the entire point of `shared_ptr` was to avoid need of deleting objects manually, not exactly this kind of issues. :-)

Comment: I'm slightly confused. Why are you trying to use `shared_ptr`s in the first place? You could just directly use pointers, and destroy them all in `GUIObjectsStorage`'s destructor.

Comment: @VisheshHanda This is what I'm doing right now, but I wanted to move to use of smart pointers as I read that it's the way to go in modern programming.

Comment: I prefer the [KISS principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle). Pointers work perfectly in this case without any risks. Other notably GUI toolkits like Qt also do not use `shared_pointer`s in their implementation `GUIObject`s. It's just simpler this way.

Comment: @VisheshHanda Thank you for this comment. :-) I thought it's really bad to stick with raw pointers in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The is a classic use of a Factory for making objects.

That said, you might not need this. Do you know when widgets are no longer needed? GUI managers like this often do. If so, the commenter is right: designate an owner of the object, let it delete it, and you're set.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider inheriting from **[enable_shared_from_this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this)**.

Then after you have a shared_ptr to the object, you can use **[shared_from_this()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this/shared_from_this)** to get the shared_ptr that holds the object.

Comment: But the problem is that I don't yet have any `shared_ptr`, because I'd like to use it in constructor, which is yet before object construction.