# How to not call base class destructor from constructor on exception?

Tags: c++, c++11, exception, constructor, destructor

I have some classes `Daughter1` and `Daughter2` inherited from `Mother`:

```
class   Mother
{
public:
    Mother(); // Empty constructor.
    virtual ~Mother(); // Delete common daughter's stuff.

protected:
    // Common stuff of each daughter.
};
```

The common stuff of every daughter class has the same deletion method, so the mother is in charge. However, their initialization is not the same, so they are in respective daughter's constructors:

```
class   Daughter1 : public Mother
{
public:
    Daughter1(); // Initialize mother's stuff
    ~Daughter1();
};

class   Daughter2 : public Mother
{
public:
    Daughter2(); // Initialize mother's stuff in a different way than Daughter1
    ~Daughter2();
};
```

The problem is: sometimes, a daughter constructor can fail to load its stuff and throws an exception. And when I declare a Daughter like this:

```
Daughter1   daughter;
```

And the constructor throws an exception, it calls the mother's destructor, which try to delete its stuff without an initialization, that lead inevitably to a segmentation fault.

What is the best way to avoid this kind of trouble?

---

Most of my stuff is composed of pointers, so I know I could simply initialize them to `nullptr` in the mother constructor and check them before trying a deletion in the destructor, but it only works with pointer and I'm looking for a global solution.

Comment: It's hard to suggest something constructive without seeing what `Mother::Mother` does.

Comment: @RSahu the mother constructor is empty. I added the precision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be deleting uninitialised pointers in your `Mother` destructor - just change the pointers to smart pointers e.g. `std::unique_ptr` and they'll `delete` themselves only when needed.

More generally, `~Mother` is only called if the `Mother` base class completed construction, and then each member variable should be in a state where any destructor can safely run.  For types like `double` and `int` there's nothing to destruct, so nothing needs to be done.  Use smart pointers instead of raw pointers, or standard containers / `std::string` instead of your own hackery.  More generally, look for or make classes that follow [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) principles to ensure they clean themselves up properly.

> simply initialize them to `nullptr` in the mother constructor and check them before trying a deletion in the destructor

FWIW, it's not necessary to check them before `delete`... `delete` of a `nullptr` is a (safe) no-op.  Put another way, any check you add will be redundant and may waste time when the pointer's not `nullptr`.

Comment: But wouldn't be finally the same than initialize them to `nullptr` and delete them only if they are not `nullptr` anymore ?

Comment: @Aracthor: yes, it's pretty much the same thing, except it's inherent in the type and doesn't need to be coordinated across the constructor and destructor, where you're more likely to forget to do initialisation and/or deletion for some member occasionally....

Answer (score 2):

Mother's stuff should be initialized by Mother's constructor, not Daughter's. Pass any required initialization parameters as constructor arguments to Mother's constructor, instead of (I assume you are doing) using assignment statements in Daughter constructor.

Code the Mother so that a Mother can be constructed and destroyed correctly on its own without relying on any derived class's activity.

`Daughter1   daughter();` declares a function, there is no constructor called.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution would be using static methods to create Daughter objects (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15596787/static-method-to-create-an-object-instead-of-constructor)) instead of real constructors. In this case you can make constructors very light-weight and non-throwing, simply put all the complex logic into these static methods.